# How to send mail programmatically using RPC over HTTP?

Tags: c#, email, rpc

How to send mail programmatically using RPC over HTTP, what are the configurations needed for that ?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some context to make it answerable. Is your question about how to send e-mail on an Exchange Server when you are outside the firewall and unable to use SMTP but where Outlook clients can connect to the server using RPC over HTTP?

Comment: Ya..through outlook client can connect the server and send mail using RPC over HTTP.So I also have to develop mail concept programmatically using RPC over HTTP.So what are the configurations needed for that ?

Comment: I doubt that RPC over HTTP like Outlook uses it is a viable option. If your question is "which API should I use to access an Exchange Server if I want to send mail" the answer is __Exchange Web Services__ or __EWS__.

Comment: Is this API is enough to send mail? or I have to install outlook also?

Comment: You do not need to install Outlook to use EWS. However, you can also automate Outlook to send a mail using COM. As I said before, your question is missing some details about what problem you are trying to solve making it hard to provide an answer.

Comment: Is both RPC over HTTP and Exchange Web Services are same?

Comment: No, RPC over HTTP and EWS are not the same.

Comment: How to get mail exchange server name of my email id?